# Этимология слова «подхалим»

Tags: этимология, словообразование, корень-слова

Подхалим — он же лизоблюд, он же блюдолиз, он же льстец и т. д. Собственно, значение слова ни у кого вопросов не вызывает. А вот о его происхождении хотелось бы узнать.
Например, тут явно видна приставка **под-**, но кто такой, извиняюсь, "халим"?
В общем, было бы очень интересно узнать происхождение корня слова "подхалим".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее от «обхаживать», «ухаживать». Ведь «холить» происходит от «холка». Не так давно люди вместо автомобилей держали лошадей, а расчёсывая гриву, растущую на **холке** у своих питомцев, они совершали действие, которое и породило такое слово как **холить**. Правда, вышеупомянутые слова обхаживать и ухаживать подходят подхалимажу более по семантике, а вот  **халат**, породившее слово **халатный** (ранее как **ленный**, а ныне **безответственный**), близко и по звучанию. Вполне возможно, действо, когда холоп (обратите внимание и на это слово) подавал барину **халат**, и обозначилось, как **подхалимаж**: **под**ача **хал**ата.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего от слова  ХОЛИТЬ.

Answer (score 1):

подхалим
Искон. Суф.-преф. производное от той же основы, что нахал, холуй. Ср. аналогичное по структуре побратим.
подхалим — Но мнению Долобко (Сб. Соболевскому 230), от *хoliti (см. холить), первонач. избалованный человек . Далее сюда же нахал, болг. охален распущенный ; см. также Желтов, ФЗ, 1876, вып. 1, стр. 23; Горяев, Доп. 1, 51 …   Этимологический словарь русского языка Макса Фасмера

Answer (score 0):

Слово "халим" у арабов, татар и крымских татар является именем. Переводится как мягкий, добрый, в чём то женственный, мягкотелый, подкаблучник (человек, не имеющий своей воли и не принимающий решения самостоятельно). Приставка "под" и "халим".

Comment: Да причем тут арабский или татарский? Ну я еще могу понять объяснение через заимствование (хотя для арабского таких примеров немного), но чтобы к нему русская приставка приклеилась...

Answer (score -1):

Анализ слова "подхалим"

Подхалим > pod-xalim > pod-xvalnj - подхвальный (слав.)(пропуск v) от сущ. хвала; подхваливать, т.е. льстить.

Есть аналог в чувашском языке "мухтав"
мухтав – слава, хвала (чув.) > muxtab > batxum > pod-xalim - подхалим (слав.)(пропуск l)

есть интересный баннер на дороге Чувашии:
мухтав мухтав сана, табан елек ен !
перевод:
«Тысяча похвал тебе Родина, Яльчинский край».

По славянски:

"Тясяча подхалим тебе, становой Яльчинский кон", где 
тыс та > тысяча (слав.)
мухтав – похвальный (слав.)
табан –родина (чув.) > taban > stanovj – становой (слав.)(проп. s, редукция v/b) от сущ. 
стан (Татар-стан, Узбеки-стан и т.д)
ен – край (чув.) > ken – кон, конец (слав.)(проп. к)